# Looping logic in JSON in java

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON array. The JSON is mentioned below. Each JSON element has a field type. What I need is, if the current field type is descriptive, I have to get the nexts array elements until I encounter the next descriptive field type.

```
{  
      "field_name":"form_name_1",
      "form_name":"patient_details",
      "section_header":"",
      "field_type":"descriptive",
      "field_label":"<font size=3><i><b>Informed Consent<\/b><\/i><\/font>",
      "select_choices_or_calculations":"",
      "field_note":"",
      "text_validation_type_or_show_slider_number":"",
      "text_validation_min":"",
      "text_validation_max":"",
      "identifier":"",
      "branching_logic":"",
      "required_field":"",
      "custom_alignment":"",
      "question_number":"",
      "matrix_group_name":"",
      "matrix_ranking":"",
      "field_annotation":""
   },
   {  
      "field_name":"vst_1_scrn_date",
      "form_name":"patient_details",
      "section_header":"",
      "field_type":"text",
      "field_label":"Visit 1 (Screening) Date:",
      "select_choices_or_calculations":"",
      "field_note":"",
      "text_validation_type_or_show_slider_number":"date_dmy",
      "text_validation_min":"",
      "text_validation_max":"",
      "identifier":"",
      "branching_logic":"",
      "required_field":"y",
      "custom_alignment":"",
      "question_number":"",
      "matrix_group_name":"",
      "matrix_ranking":"",
      "field_annotation":""
   },
   {  
      "field_name":"consent_yes_no",
      "form_name":"patient_details",
      "section_header":"",
      "field_type":"yesno",
      "field_label":"Has the subject given written informed consent?",
      "select_choices_or_calculations":"",
      "field_note":"",
      "text_validation_type_or_show_slider_number":"",
      "text_validation_min":"",
      "text_validation_max":"",
      "identifier":"",
      "branching_logic":"",
      "required_field":"y",
      "custom_alignment":"",
      "question_number":"",
      "matrix_group_name":"",
      "matrix_ranking":"",
      "field_annotation":""
   },
   {  
      "field_name":"patient_site_num",
      "form_name":"patient_details",
      "section_header":"",
      "field_type":"text",
      "field_label":"Patient site number:",
      "select_choices_or_calculations":"",
      "field_note":"",
      "text_validation_type_or_show_slider_number":"number",
      "text_validation_min":"",
      "text_validation_max":"",
      "identifier":"",
      "branching_logic":"",
      "required_field":"y",
      "custom_alignment":"",
      "question_number":"",
      "matrix_group_name":"",
      "matrix_ranking":"",
      "field_annotation":""
   },
   {  
      "field_name":"patient_letter_code",
      "form_name":"patient_details",
      "section_header":"",
      "field_type":"text",
      "field_label":"Patient letter code:",
      "select_choices_or_calculations":"",
      "field_note":"",
      "text_validation_type_or_show_slider_number":"",
      "text_validation_min":"",
      "text_validation_max":"",
      "identifier":"",
      "branching_logic":"",
      "required_field":"y",
      "custom_alignment":"",
      "question_number":"",
      "matrix_group_name":"",
      "matrix_ranking":"",
      "field_annotation":""
   },
   {  
      "field_name":"site_num",
      "form_name":"patient_details",
      "section_header":"",
      "field_type":"text",
      "field_label":"Site Number:",
      "select_choices_or_calculations":"",
      "field_note":"Belfast=01, Birmingham=02, Edinburgh=03, Imperial=04, Leicester=05, Manchester=06, Nottingham=07, Southhampton=08",
      "text_validation_type_or_show_slider_number":"number",
      "text_validation_min":"1",
      "text_validation_max":"10",
      "identifier":"",
      "branching_logic":"",
      "required_field":"y",
      "custom_alignment":"",
      "question_number":"",
      "matrix_group_name":"",
      "matrix_ranking":"",
      "field_annotation":""
   },
   {  
      "field_name":"early_cohort_num",
      "form_name":"patient_details",
      "section_header":"",
      "field_type":"text",
      "field_label":"Early cohort number:",
      "select_choices_or_calculations":"",
      "field_note":"",
      "text_validation_type_or_show_slider_number":"number",
      "text_validation_min":"1000001",
      "text_validation_max":"10009999",
      "identifier":"",
      "branching_logic":"",
      "required_field":"y",
      "custom_alignment":"",
      "question_number":"",
      "matrix_group_name":"",
      "matrix_ranking":"",
      "field_annotation":""
   },
   {  
      "field_name":"form_name_2",
      "form_name":"visit_1_screening",
      "section_header":"",
      "field_type":"descriptive",
      "field_label":"<font size=3><i><b><u>Demographics<i><\/b><\/u><\/font>",
      "select_choices_or_calculations":"",
      "field_note":"",
      "text_validation_type_or_show_slider_number":"",
      "text_validation_min":"",
      "text_validation_max":"",
      "identifier":"",
      "branching_logic":"",
      "required_field":"",
      "custom_alignment":"",
      "question_number":"",
      "matrix_group_name":"",
      "matrix_ranking":"",
      "field_annotation":""
   },
   {  
      "field_name":"dob",
      "form_name":"visit_1_screening",
      "section_header":"",
      "field_type":"text",
      "field_label":"Date of Birth:",
      "select_choices_or_calculations":"",
      "field_note":"",
      "text_validation_type_or_show_slider_number":"date_dmy",
      "text_validation_min":"",
      "text_validation_max":"",
      "identifier":"",
      "branching_logic":"",
      "required_field":"y",
      "custom_alignment":"",
      "question_number":"",
      "matrix_group_name":"",
      "matrix_ranking":"",
      "field_annotation":""
   }
```

Comment: Why don't you try translating your question into code?

`while (JSON array has more elements) { if (current JSON element has 'descriptive' value in json_type field) { do something with it } }`

Comment: If the current field type is descriptive, I have to store the successive json elements, until I encounter another descriptive field type. This has to be repeated until all the json elements are exhausted.

The idea is: the descriptive text indicates a new section. I have to isolate the json elements for each section.

Comment: I'm stuck on the logic here. If the current element is descriptive, check the next element, and if it's not descriptive, store that element in a JSON array, and look for the next element, and so on. Stop when you find a descriptive field type, and repeat the above process, and store the elements in another JSON array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will give you a HashSet with JSON arrays containing the objects for each section.

```
String json = "[{\"field_type\":\"descriptive\"},"
            + "{\"field_type\":\"test1\"},"
            + "{\"field_type\":\"descriptive\"}"
            + "{\"field_type\":\"test2\"}"
            + "]";

    HashSet<JSONArray> arrayStore = new HashSet<JSONArray>();
    JSONArray store = new JSONArray();
    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(json);
    for(int i =0; i < arr.length(); i++){
        JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
        if("descriptive".equals(obj.getString("field_type"))){
            store = new JSONArray(); // create a new array for each section...
            arrayStore.add(store); //store the current object
        } else {
            store.put(obj); //store the object in the array
        }
    }
```

Hope this is what you look for

Comment: Thank you. I did without using Hashset.

Comment: if(temp.getFieldType()=="descriptive")
           {
            desc_count=desc_count+1;
           }
         
           String[] form_desc=new String[json_length];    
           form_desc[desc_count]=form_x[count];
           System.out.println(form_desc[desc_count]+",");

Comment: It's hard to read your example when it's not formatted and not complete. 

You are using `==` to compare the strings but the `==` tests for reference equality and `.equals()` tests for value equality. Good practice is to use `"descriptive".equals(temp.getFieldType())` to avoid NPE. 

Instead of `desc_count=desc_count+1;` you can use `desc_count++`


If you found my answer useful please accept it.